# How can we get more questions like the one about villages monitoring well water levels?

Tags: discussion

[How to motivate villagers to monitor well water levels of their wells?](https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/1503/how-to-motivate-villagers-to-monitor-well-water-levels-of-their-wells)

Really super interesting question, and a way I think we might want to figure out how to increase our community's scope and appeal.

Answer (score 5):

I agree that that is a great question. More of these types of questions would help make it more obvious that our scope includes "physical communities", in addition to the digital ones that *most* of our questions focus on.

Part of getting questions like this, though, means we need to be able to answer them. This high quality question deserves a high quality, well researched and actionable answer. When we can provide that, I think we can use this type of question to show we have experts that know the "physical communities" aspect as well. Many of our best answers take time to research/write so I'm confident that we'll get an answer, eventually, but it may take a bit.